# MySQL - How can I/workaround ordering by the result of a group function

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I'm using `MySQL 5.5.37-0` `ubuntu0.12.04.1`

I have the following MySQL table for a football game..

G = Goal
M = Missed
S = Saved

```
id|  team  | result

0, "England", "G",
1, "France",  "M",
2, "England", "G",
3, "Germany", "G",
4, "Germany", "S",
```

etc...

I need to create a league table of the best team by ordering by their goal to miss ratio...

I'd like to do the following...

---

```
SELECT `team` as 'target',
(
    SELECT count(`id`)
    FROM `database`
    WHERE `team` = `target`
) as 'shots',
count(`id`) AS 'goals'
FROM `database`
WHERE (
    `result` =  'G'
)
GROUP BY `team`
ORDER BY (`goals` / `shots`) DESC
Limit 0, 10
</code>
```

But you can't order group functions. Is there an alternative method of doing this?

Thanks.

Comment: England - G - unlikely, but we can live in hope. What would the desired result look like?

Comment: May be possible in this WC

Comment: I may have made up the test data :) I can order by just `goals` but I'd like to order by `goals`, (then) `ratio`. Not to dissimilarly to a real league table

Comment: Take a look at my answer, I don't know why it got down voted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can order by fields, but you need to surround your query by another one, that does this.

```
    SELECT target, goals / shot as ratio from (
        SELECT `team` as 'target',
            (
            SELECT count(`id`)
                FROM `database`
                WHERE `team` = `target`
            ) as 'shots',
            count(`id`) AS 'goals'
        FROM `database`
        WHERE (
            `result` =    'G'
        )
        GROUP BY `team`
        Limit 0, 10) foo
    ORDER BY goals DESC, ratio DESC
```

Comment: Thanks colburton. This seems to work perfectly. Can anyone explain the downvote?

Comment: Maybe because I had a falty version posted before I saw my mistake.

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT COUNT(result)  shots,
    (SELECT COUNT(result) AS Goal FROM football 
                    WHERE result='g' AND team = f.team
                    ) goal
    ,team , ((SELECT COUNT(result) AS Goal FROM football 
                    WHERE result='g' AND team = f.team))/COUNT(result)  AS ratio

FROM football f
GROUP BY team 


ORDER BY ratio DESC
```

please try this query and let me know I create your table as you mention in your question and try to find ration of strike and goal done....